# Равная выборка элементов из массива.

Tags: php

Здравствуйте!

Делаю Landing Page, мне нужна небольшая система А-Б тестирования. Собственно, у меня есть три страницы, и массив:

```
$variable = array('a','b','c');
```

Мне нужно между ними трафик распределить равномерно. Пока что я это делаю с помощью функции:

```
$var = array_rand($input, 1);
```

Но пока не знаю на сколько он равномерно распределяет посетителей по 3 страницам. Надеюсь на вашу помощь.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если надо выдавать в одинаковых пропорциях, то храните данные о том сколько раз отдавали страницы в БД. При запросе страницы вытаскивайте эти данные и отдавайте ту страницу, которую отдавали меньше всего раз, и так постоянно. Логика тривиальна.

Comment: Думаю файлами будет проще хранить инфу. Трафик не будет слишком бешенный, по 100 уников в день думаю максимум.

Answer (score 2):

Я не поленился:

```
$choices = [1,2,3];
$counters = [1 => 0, 2 => 0, 3 => 0];
for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
    $choice = $choices[array_rand($choices)];
    $counters[$choice]++;
}
var_dump($counters);

...

fike@aves:/srv/http/src/blogmvc/Yii$ php ~/Temp/php/shorts/rand.php 
array(3) {
  [1] =>
  int(33325)
  [2] =>
  int(33214)
  [3] =>
  int(33461)
}
```

Разброса в плюс-минус полторы десятой процента достаточно?

---

ОК, хорошо, проверим по-другому.

```
// rand.php

$counters = array_fill_keys([1,2,3], 0);
ob_start();
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $choice = (int) system('php '.__DIR__.'/rand_helper.php');
    $counters[$choice]++;
}
ob_end_clean();
var_dump($counters);

// rand_helper.php
$choices = [1,2,3];
echo $choices[array_rand($choices)];

// out
array(3) {
  [1] =>
  int(344)
  [2] =>
  int(330)
  [3] =>
  int(326)
}
```

максимально замеченный разброс около 3% (16) на 500 значениях, понятия не имею нормально ли это для такого размера выборки.

Comment: А разве после обновления страницы, ну либо когда заходит другой юзер, у него же скрипт с нуля загружается, то есть каждый раз массив обновляется. Я понятно выразился? Данные массива должны храниться во внешнем файле в таком случае.

Comment: @chuikoff, обновил. Но, как вы понимаете, я веду не совсем к этому.

Comment: Так а 1000 это что? Тот трафик что я хочу нагнать? А если я заранее не знаю сколько людей прийдёт?

Comment: @chuikoff, вот ведь ты хорош-то, а.

Я всячески намекаю на то, что это действительно рандом. Он, возможно, предугадываем в момент создания, но это неважно, потому что распределение он обесчивает.  
Более того, вероятность его зависимости от запуска скрипта примерна равна нулю. Он не создает рандомное число, он наверняка тянет его из ОС.  
А еще я намекаю на то, что да, хранить в файле/бд последний показанный вариант, если есть такие страхи. Хранить в нем последний выбранный вариант и брать потом следующий, и записывать его в тот же файл для следующего запроса. Распределение будет **ровно** 1/

Comment: Ну и в превую очередь я конечно намекаю на то, что такие вещи тестируются скриптом из менее двадцати строк.